# Mismatched L3 programming layer with Editorial Manager

Tags: journal-publishing

I am trying to submit revisions for a paper to a journal (IJHCS), which uses the Aries Editorial Manager system. When I do this however, I get the following error:

```
(LaTeX) Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)
(LaTeX) The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX) is dated 2023-02-07, but in your TeX tree the files
require
(LaTeX) at least 2023-02-22.
```

Is there any way to specify the version of the L3 layer in my local tex engine? I'm not sure this would help but I cannot think of anything else at the moment.

It compiles perfectly locally, both with TinyTex and MikTex.

Thanks

Comment: You could update your local TeX installation to the latest version.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667733/the-l3-programming-layer-in-the-latex-format-is-outdated are you uploading a very new package requiring 2023-02-22,in which case use an older one, or is their input tree broken, in which case it's a bug they should fix

Comment: @Skillmon I think the issue is tex is running on the publisher's server

Comment: I'm trying it now with an older version of elsarticle.cls so will see if that works - cheers folks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, there is a slight chance I misunderstood the question... I interpreted it this way because of the "Is there any way to specify the version of the L3 layer in my local tex engine?", not sure what exactly is needed.

Comment: @GabrielStrain are you getting that error when you run the document locally or when you submit a tex file to the publisher's server? You have given very little information in the question

Comment: Only when I submit to the publisher's server - the reason I asked about that is so I could try and make them match

Comment: might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674366/36296

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz